# Can I make a closure of an async function to pass as a promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, promise

I have a `somedataMap : Map<string, Promise<SomeData>>` that I would like to populate.

I also have an async function `async function getSomeData(someIdentifier:string): Promise<SomeData>`, that I would like use as the values in that map

Obviously if I do something like `somedataMap.set("someId", getSomeData("someId"))`, then the code in `getSomeData` is called, which I don't want to do until *maybe* later. What is the best way to wrap/closure the `getSomeData` function as a Promise so I can store it or pass it to other functions?

Comment: If you can't change the type of the Map, then you cannot do this.

Comment: all Promises attempt to resolve immediately? I thought they were in limbo until await or .then were used

Comment: Whether you await it or not, the Promise will run regardless.

Comment: I suppose the confusion for me is a `()=>Data` function could be stored without being called, but a Promise<Data> which in my mind is just a `async () => Data` function apparently cannot

Comment: A Promise would be the result of **calling** an async function, not the async function itself.

Comment: Fair. I guess I have no choice but to use functions as values instead

Comment: "*the code in `getSomeData` is called, which I don't want to do until maybe later*" - so when exactly do you want to call the function?

Comment: There are two parts to Promis-es. I always use the ordering take-away analogy. You order take-away food from a restaurant. To do that you make a phone call. **The phone call happens NOW**. The food comes later. Similarly, when you call a function that returns a promise the function logic happens **NOW**. The result (which may come from half-way around the world via the internet or from a USB thumb drive) comes later. It is the callback passed to `.then()` that gets executed later, not the logic wrapped in `new Promise()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either

```js
somedataMap: Map<string, () => Promise<SomeData>>

somedataMap.set("someId", () => getSomeData("someId"))
```

OR

use it as it is, and later, when you want to receive value from Promise, do the following:

```js
await somedataMap.get("someId")
```

Comment: I cannot change the type of the map, which I assume is what you mean by "use it as it is", but that's the problem, I don't know how to use it as it is. I don't want the `getSomeData` function being called until someone pulls the promise from the map, like you've done there with the await

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want the `getSomeData` function being called until someone pulls the promise from the map

Unless you overwrite the `get` method of the map (which you should not do), this is not possible. Rather, write a separate wrapper function for pulling values:

```
const somedataMap = new Map<string, Promise<SomeData>>();
function pull(id) {
  let promise = somedataMap.get(id);
  if (!promise) {
    promise = getSomeData(id);
    somedataMap.set(id, promise);
    // promise.catch(() => { somedataMap.delete(id); }); ???
  }
  return promise;
}
```

Then use it as

```
await pull("someId")
```

Answer (score -1):

Async functions *are* promises. You don't need to wrap it. Just call it.

```js
const getSomeData = async (id) => {
  return 'some data';
};

const somedataMap = new Map();

getSomeData('x').then(data => {

  console.log(`data is "${data}"`);

  somedataMap.set("someId", data);

  console.log( somedataMap.values().next().value );

});
```